# DLookup file path source

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to determine how a file path value on a shared server (output of the DLookUp function in Access) is getting populated.

I have a field on a Form that is getting it's Control Source from the following formula:

`=DLookUp("[DefaultOuptputDir]","Defaults")`

When I search in the VB Editor, I can not find any references at all to "DefaultOuptputDir" (the spelling is correct as it was originally created). I can also not find any reference to the actual Path being populated below, so I don't believe it is hardcoded in a form.

Ultimately I want to change this path to one I can access, but I need to understand how this is getting populated now. Looking for input on what I should be checking, thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will be the value stored in the first record of a field called DefaultOuptputDir In a table called Defaults.

Comment: So simple and I overlooked checking there. Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 2):

`DLookUp` is a function which searches table for some criteria and returns some field

```
DLookUp(field, table, criteria)
```

In your case it shows value of `DefaultOutputDir` in table `Defaults` and i suspect this table have only one row so the third argumet is ommited.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, it was indeed in the table Defaults.